# Twitter API and OAuth1.0a- automatically logging a user out

Tags: actionscript-3, twitter, twitter-oauth

Using this excellent Twitter for AS3 library
https://github.com/susisu/Twitter-for-AS3/blob/master/README_en.md

Once a user is logged in to their account, I need to be able to automatically log them out after a specified action. In my case uploading an image.

Does anyone know how to do this with the latest twitter API?

Answer (score 0):

Log them out of Twitter or your app? The former, I guess would be pretty annoying. For the latter, is https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/oauth2/invalidate_token what you're looking for?

> Allows a registered application to revoke an issued OAuth 2 Bearer
>   Token by presenting its client credentials. Once a Bearer Token has
>   been invalidated, new creation attempts will yield a different Bearer
>   Token and usage of the invalidated token will no longer be allowed.

Comment: thanks but no. A bearer token is for application only authentication. And yes, I meant log them out of twitter. I instead am using "force_login=true" when sending the oauth/authorize request for the login form. Doesn't log out a user, but at least a blank login form is presented.